# Netbeans 7.3 and git integration: where is the git client used by Netbeans?

Tags: git, netbeans

In my Netbeans 7.3, i tried to init a git repository via gui, and apparently it has worked. 
Then tried to launch the command-line client that I more familiar with and i discovered that apparently on this (Windows 7) machine there is no git client. It is not installed as a stand-alone client, neither it is inside Netbeans. 
The questions are:

1. does Netbeans have a internal (java based) git client? 
   If so, the docs are not up to date because they state (from netbeans help):

   Before you can take advantage of the IDE's Git support, you need to have Git client software
   installed on your system. The IDE supports Git client versions 1.7.x and higher.
2. i want to operate via command line, to reduce possibile problems i want to use the same git version (or git "repository version")that netbeans uses. How can i determine such a version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that NB 7.3/7.4 uses JGit. BTW egit is also based on jGit. Only IntelliJ Idea uses your native cli git client

Answer (score 2):

1) the version supported in Netbeans you can find out: menu "Tools" --> option "Plugins", select the tab "Installed", when you select the Git plugin on the right you can see the version
2) to have a CLI version of git you might have have a look here https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Comment: Don't forget the "Show details" checkbox in the "Installed" tab.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know NetBeans uses [JGit](http://www.jgit.org/).